# Ember 'needs' dependencies between unrelated controllers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 models in Ember Data: a `Tag` has and belongs to many `Files`, both models being loaded via JSON from a Rails backend.  My URLs are not deep nested because of the many-to-many nature of the relationship.  Here is the code to set that up in Ember:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'tags', ->
  @resource 'tag',
    path: 'tags/:tag_id'
  , ->
  @resource 'file',
    path: 'files/:file_id'
  , ->

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  files: DS.hasMany('file',
    async: true
  )

App.File = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag',
    async: true
  )
```

In the `tags` page I display a list of all tags - no issues here.  In the `tags/:tag_id` page I display the list of files having that tag - also no issues.  In the `files/:file_id` page I want to display some information about the file, with the ability to do things such as edit the tags belonging to that file.  Doing so requires me to have the list of all tags, both belonging and not belonging to that file, loaded in Ember, but since the routes are not in the same hierarchy chain, I can't for example do

```
App.FileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: 'tags'
  tags: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.tags.content') # undefined
```

to obtain the data I need, although if this were possible, it would be exactly what I need.  It also doesn't make sense to pass in all the JSON for all the tags (especially the ones not belonging to the file) in that route.

What are my options at this point?  I'm guessing I have to restructure the code to make the `tags` information accessible in the `ApplicationController` and calling `needs: 'application'`.  I haven't quite figured out how to do load the correct JSON in the `ApplicationController`.  Is there an alternate/better way that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would set the content of the tags controller in your FileRoute.

```
App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
    init: ()->
        @_super()
        @generateController('tags')

    setupController : (controller, model) ->
        @_super(controller, model)       
        @controllerFor('tags').set('model', @get('store').find('tag'))

)
```

That way, you can keep all your other code but I think you should use Ember.computed.alias('controllers.tags.model') instead of Ember.computed.alias('controllers.tags.content').

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws an error: "Error while processing route: file.index Assertion Failed: The controller named 'tags' could not be found. Make sure that this route exists and has already been entered at least once. If you are accessing a controller not associated with a route, make sure the controller class is explicitly defined."  It seems like for this to work, the resources must be nested...

Comment: You are right. It worked in my case, but the route was already entered once. I edited the answer, now it should work.